# How to give path of image from external JavaScript file in making Flask API?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flask

I want to change the attribute value in the *index.html* file from the external JavaScript file linked to that HTML file.

I have folder structure as: [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpHFC.png)

I can easily give path from html file using: `{{url_for('static', filename='image_path')}}`

 But, this does not work while using in external JavaScript file.

```
     success: function (data) {
        var image_name = data["img_name"]
        var image_path = data["image_path"]

// I have image_path and image_name ready but could not find the exact method to use this...
// I want to use the image saved in "uploads" folder
        
        document.getElementById("uploadimg").setAttribute("src", {{url_for('uploads', filename='image_name')}});

      }
```

So, How can I use the absolute path or image_name to change the image in the frontend?
Thanks!

Comment: By the way, instead of using `setAttribute` image elements have the built-in `src` property, so you could just do `document.getElementById("uploadimg").src = ...;`.

Comment: Couldn't you return the full path of the image from the server and just set `document.getElementById("uploadimg").src = data["full_image_path"];`

Answer (score 1):

A common technique used by server-rendered pages is to create a JSON script thing in their HTML and query it from the (external) JS.

For example, in your Flask server, you'd so something like:

```py
import json

# ...
@app.route("/page")
def page():
  data = json.dumps({
    "uploadImageUrl": url_for("uploads", filename="image_name")
    # you can include other data
  })
  return render_template("page.html", data=data)
```

Then stick this into your `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="application/json" id="data">{{ data }}</script>
```

Note that the browser only executes JavaScript when it is in a script with type `text/javascript` (default value if not specified), so when we add `application/json`, the browser will just leave our weird-smelling script tag alone.

In your external JavaScript you could do something like:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("data"));

// somewhere else in your code:
document.getElementById("uploadimg").setAttribute("src", data.uploadImageUrl);
```